# Help solve a Diff: equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am pretty new to calculus so please anyone help me solve this differential equation

$\frac{dy}{dx}=(yx-2y-3x+6)^{0.5}$

Comment: It's equivalent to $\frac{dy}{\sqrt{y - 3}} = \sqrt{x - 2}dx$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{xy-2x-3y+6} \implies \int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{y-3}}= \int dx \sqrt{x-2}.$$
$$\implies 2\sqrt{y-3}=\frac{2}{3}(x-2)^{3/2}+C $$

Comment: The $x$ integral is wrong

Comment: Oh! sorry I have corrected it now. Thanks.